# How can I block users from accessing a section of my website at a specific time of day?

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a chat feature on my website that I've mentioned in other questions.  There are some kids at my school who would love to chat during school, but I'd really rather they'd just chat during study hall so I don't get in trouble for interrupting class time.  How can I restrict user movement on my website during specific time periods during the day?  Thanks!  I don't know what type of scripting language I might need for this, but I'm assuming PHP since this is a server issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php date("H"); ?>
```

returns the current hour in a 24 hour format with leading zeroes.

That means, you can write something like this:

```
<?php

if (date("H") == 14)){
   die("You cannot get here right now");
}

?>
```

This will "die" echoing the page, and will return the error instead, exactly during the 14th hour of the day (2:00 pm).

Give us more code/details to get a deeper answer.

**EDIT:** This is an expanded answer to the new question, asking,

> Study hall at my school is 2:30 to 3:15, so how would I do that?

**SOLUTION:** Assuming study hall is the time when the students are **allowed** to use the (section of) the site, you would do something like this:

```
<?php

$bottomValue = 60*14+30;
$upperValue = 60*15+15;
$currentValue = date("G")*60+date("i");

if (($currentValue >= $bottomValue) && ($currentValue <= $upperValue)){
   // everything is OK = put some code here, or ignore this
}
else{
   // well, this is the time they are not allowed to see this, so, let's try:
   die("Sorry, you are not allowed to be here right now.");  
}

?>
```

To explain how this works: your time base is counted into minutes as `$bottomValue` and `$upperValue`. Notice how they are defined, it's 60 minutes multiplied by hour (14) plus minutes (30).

So, 14:30 is `60*14+30`, therefore, 16:20 would be `60*16+20`.

Then the base is compared to the current time and an appropriate code is executed according to the if/else statements.

Comment: study hall at my school is 2:30 to 3:15, so how would I do that?

Comment: to be honest, it is a sort of unusual situation, it gave me some hard time thinking too, but I think I came up with a very clean solution. hope it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also control access via your web server; Apache, for example, [allows time-based access controls in `mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html#rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >20 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <07
RewriteRule ^/chat - [F]
```

@RiMMER's PHP-based solution may be easier to read, write, and modify, but server-based mechanisms won't require inserting a check into every page.

Comment: He is talking about "a section of his website", which MIGHT be only a certain php file which is being included (like a site widget) and MAY NOT be disabled by your method. If I'm wrong, then your method is great too.

Comment: @RiMMER, good point -- depending upon how his site is written, either my mechanism or your mechanism would be easier to be precise about which specific portions are time-limited. Either one could do the same job, but getting it _clean_ could be vastly different. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, also consider your server's date/time settings as you use `date()` function because even you put in date and time checks on your site if the date and time of your server is not the same as your specified restricted time of the day (in your school) they may still view stuff.