# Open page at specific time

Tags: php

I would like to open access to a page at specific time frame in php.

Say for E.g 9:00AM to 12:00PM - User will be able view a page after which they would get you are not allowed to view this page at this time.

Is this possible in PHP without accessing database?

If so can somebody guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608283/how-can-i-block-users-from-accessing-a-section-of-my-website-at-a-specific-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use .htaccess directives. The idea is described here http://www.blog.highub.com/apache/http-server/htaccess-deny-diractory-access-during-a-specific-time/

Comment: Actually I tried it couple of hours back but didn't work:       SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^(8|9|10)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]


according to the code the page should not be access from 8AM to 10AM but I am not able access it even now. Time is around 20:30Hrs.

Comment: You can block access to your site from 8AM to 10AM with something like this: `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0800  
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1000  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
`

Comment: Not working Guz Alexander. The server time shows 8:15AM now but I still can access the site.:( According to your code it should not give access to me from 8 to 10AM

Comment: I figured out few things. Even though I change the system in php.ini it is still Eastern Standard time.  So now the time is 23:23 hrs. I put the above code to block the page from >2300 and <2400 the page is getting blocked without any issues but when I say block from >2300 and <0100 - I can see the page. Say for e.g can't I block website from 22:00hrs to 09:00AM

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
if(date('G')>=9 && date('G')<=11)
{
    // show your code/site/content.
}
else
{
    // Show the "Come back during opening hours..." sign.
}
```

The [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function by default uses the specific time and using `G` gives a 0-24 value for the hour of the day (no leading zeroes).

This *will* use the server time though - which is what I expect you want rather than using the user's timezone if they are not at the same timezone as your server.

If your server is in a different timezone to what you expect your users to be at, use [date-default-timezone-set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set it to where you want.